# Error in editing a spreadsheet in SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

A colleague attempts to edit an Excel spreadsheet hosted in SharePoint and gets the following error message. Why? and how to solve it?

> Sorry, but to open this workbook, your computer must be running a
>   supported version of Microsoft Excel and a browser that supports
>   opening files directly from Office Web Apps.

My colleagues has the same version of Office and IE as me (Office 2010 and IE9), but when I attempt to open the same document, it works without with error message. So what is the real cause of this error message, and how to resolve it? The version of SharePoint is SharePoint 2013.

Comment: McAfee antivirus

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin It could be the same error as with Webroots AV: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2015/06/17/sorry-but-to-open-this-workbook-your-computer-must-be-running-a-supported-version-of-microsoft-application-and-a-browser-that-supports-opening-files-directly-from-office-online/ tl;dr - Add an exception in your AV for `Interceptor.dll`, typically found at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15` (for Office 2013; adjust as necessary for your version of Office).